# using which in relative cause as an object

Tags: modal-verbs, relative-clauses, present-tense, grammatical-roles

For example, is this sentence correct?

“If your friend isn’t reliable, he/she can use the things ***which*** your friend knows about you against you.”

Comment: I don't think it is really necessary...

Comment: Does 'he/she' have an antecedent in a previous sentence? If not,  why is there a reversion to 'your friend'?

Comment: _Which_ can be used as a relative pronoun when it is subject or object, or even object of preposition. It can refer to any thing (though not any person), including abstract things like clauses.

Comment: Yes: "which"  is object of "knows".